# converting any date having timezone to UTC

Tags: php, date

I am working on converting any date having timezone to UTC.

i have offset i wants to convert UTC time from that particular time by adding/subs rating offset like +5300 can any one help me how write PHP code for the same.

I have tried following code :

```
$d = new DateTime('2010-01-31 20:30:00');
$d->modify('+5300 hours');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";`
```

Comment: What you try so far ?

Comment: 53 hours is a pretty weird timezone

Comment: updated but not working it is adding 5300 hours but i have formate of offset +5300 +1000 etc

Answer (score 0):

If the time stamp is 2010-01-31 20:30:00+5300, then you would want to do:

```
$d = new DateTime('2010-01-31 20:30:00');
$d->modify('-53 hours');
```

5300 stands for 53 hours, 0 minutes, not 5300 hours.  Also you need to subtract that to get back to UTC, it is already ahead of UTC.

Comment: actually i wants to add 5:30(5 hours 30 minutes) not 53 hours

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me.   You said you want to convert to UTC in the question.  Why don't you provide the full input and output date/timezone that you want?